# How can I print milliseconds in Hive without ignoring zeros

Tags: sql, string, datetime, hive, hiveql

I am trying to print `'YYYY-MM-d HH:mm:ss.S'` which has exact 3 milliseconds in the end.

This is what I get normally.

```
hive> select current_timestamp();
OK
2020-09-22 12:00:26.658
```

But in edge cases I also get

```
hive> select current_timestamp();
OK
2020-09-22 12:00:25.5
Time taken: 0.065 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select cast(current_timestamp() as timestamp);
OK
2020-09-22 12:00:00.09
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select current_timestamp() as string;
OK
2020-09-22 11:07:12.27
Time taken: 0.076 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

What I am expecting is not to ignore 0's at the end like:

```
hive> select current_timestamp();
OK
2020-09-22 12:00:25.500
Time taken: 0.065 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select cast(current_timestamp() as timestamp);
OK
2020-09-22 12:00:00.090
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select current_timestamp();
OK
2020-09-22 11:07:12.270
Time taken: 0.076 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

What I tried:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss.S');
unix_timestamp(void) is deprecated. Use current_timestamp instead.
OK
2020-09-22 11:09:30.0
Time taken: 0.064 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

And I also tried converting current_timestamp() as string so it wont ignore 0's but that also don't work

Answer (score 0):

Try `rpad(string str, int len, string pad)`.

[Doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF):

> Returns str, right-padded with pad to a length of len. If str is longer than len, the return value is shortened to len characters. In case of empty pad string, the return value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when if you use `date_format()`?

```
select date_format(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

Comment: Yeah I just tried it, says to_char is invalid function.

Comment: @settle: my bad, I got confused with another Apache product. `date_format()` should do it (with the same format specifier). See my edit.